# xpages managed bean property of an array returns the reference instead of the values

Tags: xpages, managed-bean

must be a rookies problem:

in a managed bean i want to put values of a multivalue notes item into a bean variable:

my snippet goes like:

```
private String[] typevalues;

public void setTypevalues(String[] typevalues) {
    this.typevalues = typevalues;
}

public String[] getTypevalues() {
    return typevalues;
}
```

and in the loadPreferences function I do sth like:

```
        Vector <String> vt = profdoc.getItemValue("ideetypes");
        typevalues = vt.toArray(new String[vt.size()]);
```

(didn't find a better way to bring a getItemValue vector into an Array)

on the xpage my test item:

```
                <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                    value="#{APr.typevalues}">
                </xp:text>
```

doesn't show the values of that String array, but it's reference like [Ljava.lang.String;@74987498

Am I missing sth, or is a String[] Array the wrong container for such a bean property?

thanks in advance, Uwe

Comment: yeah, use the ArrayList way as Howard is suggesting. Or if you use ODA you can skip the Vector part by. profdoc.getItemValue("ideetypes", List.class)

Comment: thanks Frank - ok, ODA would be another option, we didn't implement it up to now

Comment: uff - is this such a silly Q. that it is downvoted ...?!

Comment: This is NOT a silly question and there's no good reason to down vote it.  Dealing with multi-value fields in XPages and a Java Backend is a valid need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like using ArrayList and not Arrays. Then you can use the following to convert from a Vector to the ArrayList.

```
Collections.list( rtnVector.elements())
```

Howard

Comment: thanks Howard,

 i changed the definition of typevalues to ArrayList and assigned the vector to it with: typevalues = new ArrayList<String>(vt); . Now I can use the property on the xpage :-)

Comment: Great! Glad to help! Howard